# VBA loop through column, replace using drop down box

Tags: vba, excel

Very new at VBA, I need something that sounds simple but I lack the knowledge or terminology to correctly research how to do this.

I need a way to loop through a column (we'll say D) to find value (X) and prompt a dropdown box from range (T2:T160) to replace value X for each individual occurance of X in rows rows 1 to 10000.

At the same for each time X is found, the value in that row for column B needs to be displayed (the user will query an external application to determine which of the values from the range needs to be set for that unique column B value)

`1  b
2  y
3  x
4  t
5  x`

and end like this

`1  b
2  y
3  q
4  t
5  p`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I setup my data like this:

[image]

---

Main code:

```
Sub findReplace()
    Dim iReply As Integer
    Dim strName As String
    strName = InputBox(Prompt:="Enter Text to Search in Column D", Title:="Search Text", Default:="Enter value to find")

    If strName = "Enter value to find" Or strName = vbNullString Then
       Exit Sub
    Else
        For Each cell In Range("D1:D5")
            If cell.Value = Trim(strName) Then
                'Prompt to see if new value is required
                iReply = MsgBox(Prompt:="Found " & strName & vbCrLf & "Value in column B is: " & cell.Offset(0, -2).Value & vbCrLf & "Do you wish to replace it?", _
                        Buttons:=vbYesNoCancel, Title:="UPDATE MACRO")

                'Test response
                If strName = "Your Name here" Or _
                   strName = vbNullString Then
                   Exit Sub
                ElseIf iReply = vbYes Then
                    'Get new value
                    UserForm1.Show
                    ValueSelected = UserForm1.ComboBox1.Value
                    Unload UserForm1

                    If ValueSelected = vbNullString Or ValueSelected = "" Then
                        Exit Sub
                    Else
                        'Replace value
                        cell.Value = ValueSelected
                    End If
                ElseIf iReplay = vbCancel Then
                    Exit Sub
                End If
            End If
        Next cell
    End If
End Sub
```

---

Setup a UserForm1 to display a drop down list to provide the user a selection option.  Code behind form looks like this: (buttons have to be named the same to work correctly)

```
Private Sub bnt_Cancel_Click()
    Unload Me
End Sub

Private Sub btn_Okay_Click()
    Me.Hide
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    'Populate dropdown list in userform

    Dim rng As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")

    For Each rng In ws.Range("T1:T10")
        Me.ComboBox1.AddItem rng.Value
    Next rng
End Sub
```

---

When you run it you'll get this sequence of popups:

[image]

[image]

[image]

I said no to the second replacement value so now my spread sheet looks like this:

[image]

Comment: The replacement string can't be user input text, it needs to be a dropdown based on a list (of customers) elsewhere on the sheet. Some have 60+ characters and need to match specifically because later in in my code the sheet it split into 100+ sheets by customer name. Also, the search string is known and non-variable. That's alright though because I can see how to change that bit in the code you provided

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read as thoroughly as I should have.  I've updated the entire post to better fit your question.  To show a drop down list you'll need to display a userform and then get the value back into your vba module.  Hopefully this better meets your criteria.

Comment: Absolutely amazing! Hopefully I'll have some time to screw with this during the week. Many thanks! Is there a way to simplify it to remove unnecessary steps?  The search value is fixed, no need for text input, and all matching values will always need to be replaced so no need to ask for conformation.